# Irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain without invariant distribution/measure

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, examples-counterexamples

Is it possible that a Markov chain is irreducible and aperiodic but without invariant distribution or without an invariant measure?  Could someone give examples?

Comment: I can't find a reference now, but one condition that I remember being brought up for the existence of an invariant measure was that the expected return time to any state $x \in S$ is finite, i.e. $\mathbb{E}(\rho_x) < \infty, \; \forall x \in S$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if your state space is finite or not. If it is finite then stationary distribution exists. Otherwise, the MC need not be persistent and stationary distribution need not exist. Plenty of examples can be found in Karlin and Taylor’s book.

Comment: I do not have access  to this literatur. Could you post it?  Preferably such that it is transient

Comment: @JoeyDoey Queing theory has lots of such examples. In fact necessary and sufficient conditions for transience can be found in any book which discusses queing theory.

Comment: I can't find the book  you cite in your answer with just the authors, can you tell me the title?

Comment: Karlin and Taylor's 'A First Course In Stochastic Processes' and 'A Second Course In Stochastic Processes'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In your answer you wrote "Katlin" that's why I couldn't find it earlier.